# Is there a difference between "directly" and "straight"?

Tags: word-difference

> After work, I go straight home.
>   After work, I go home directly.

Are these two sentences completely the same?

According to [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/straight), "straight" has two meanings as an adverb:

1. immediately
2. clearly

whereas "directly" has its two meanings:

1. very soon or immediately
2. without anything coming in between

So, I think it will be hard to distinguish the meanings of the two words if in the situation they both mean "immediately".

Answer (score 1):

There is essentially no difference between "I go straight home" and "I go home directly." I find the latter to be a little more formal and would be less likely to use it.

Answer (score 1):

To me, "I go straight home" and "I go directly home" have the same meaning - that my route has no diversions or stops. However "I go home directly" is to me like "I go home straightaway", that is that I do not delay before leaving.